# How to show images as single line horizontal grid view with delete button in iPad

Tags: objective-c, gridview, uiimage, ipad

Hello Every One,

> I am working on a project where my requirement is to display images as
>   shown below image with delete functionality. I have gone through many
>   grid view samples like GMGridView,AQGridView etc but i am not able to
>   find the solution. So please help me out to establish below
>   functionality

Thanks,

[image: description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html) for creating UIControl like this. Using [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewFlowLayout) with collectionview you can achieve this structure.

There are lots of tutorial available outside for UICollectionview you can learn from there

Some of the links are

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_iOS_6_Collection_View_and_Flow_Layout

http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/